# How to get search results in grails if you have the domain (model) name stored in a string

Tags: hibernate, grails, model, dns, grails-orm

I have a method which has domain name as a String parameter.

```
def modelName="Equity"
```

I want to use it like

```
def results=modelName.findAll()
```

Please guide me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def packageName = 'com.myproject'
def modelName = "Equity"
def domainClass = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("$packageName.$modelName")
def results = domainClass .findAll()
```